# video playing (AVPlayer ViewController, AVkit) is not working (Does not appear)

Tags: swift, video, avfoundation, local, avkit

I searched for hours and found no solution ...
The video playing code is not working (the **local** video doesn't appear...)
I also try open video through open video with URL code they both did not work.
hope you can find solution for that, thank you!

Code Below :

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    func forbutton(name : String, type : String)  {
        func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            playVideo(name: name, type: type)
        }
    }


    private func playVideo(name : String, type : String) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "\(name)", ofType:"\(type)") else {
            debugPrint("video not found")
            return
        }
        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerController.player = player
        present(playerController, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }




    @IBAction func fatB(_ sender: Any) {
        forbutton(name: "fatB", type: "mp4")

    }


    @IBAction func coderB(_ sender: Any) {

        forbutton(name: "birdC", type: "mp4")
    }


    @IBAction func clashB(_ sender: Any) {

        forbutton(name: "clash", type: "mp4")
    }
```

Comment: I'd recommend moving `viewDidAppear` out of the `forbutton` function.

Comment: I tried but the problem is that this method does not accept parameters, and I need to change them for each button

Comment: no, the problem is that you have a function definition within another function. that won't work for what you're trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you're inserting a function inside another , it should be

```
func forbutton(name : String, type : String)  {

    playVideo(name: name, type: type)

}
```

If you want to play it when view appears

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    forbutton(name: "fatB", type: "mp4")
}
```

Comment: The code jumps keep sending me "video unavailable" although I added the videos through build phases. You know why?